# Is this an appropriate use of Composition over Inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, composition

**Background**

I have a base class `BaseObject`, which I want to use throughout an application. The `BaseObject` really only defines a public `Guid` which all objects in the application must have; in addition the `BaseObject` defines a number of methods to assist in generating property change events. This resulted in the following code:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    private Guid id;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { ChangeProperty(ref id, value, "Id"); }
    }

    protected virtual void ChangeProperty<T>(
        ref T property,
        T value,
        string propertyName)
    {
        // Change the property and generate events
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Since ALL objects had to inherit from `BaseObject`, this meant that a derived class would have a 'fixed' `ChangeProperty`. I I wanted to modify `ChangeProperty` so that it outputs to the console I would have had to modify the base class.

**Potential Solution**

The code that I've re-written now looks like the following; I've got a separate class to handle the property changes:

```
public interface IPropertyChangeHelper
{
    void ChangeProperty<T>(
        ref T property,
        T value,
        string propertyName,
        PropertyChangingEventHandler changingHandler,
        PropertyChangedEventHandler changedHandler);
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    // passed in during construction
    private readonly IPropertyChangeHelper propertyChangeHelper; 

    private Guid id;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { ChangeProperty(ref id, value, "Id"); }
    }

    // Forwarding method
    protected virtual void ChangeProperty<T>(
        ref T property,
        T value,
        string propertyName)
    {
        // Forward to helper
    }
}
```

**Could someone please provide some feedback as to whether I'm proceeding down the correct path regarding composability/inheritance?**

Comment: why do you have to change the base-class if you have a `virtual` member here? It looks like your base-class itself is really only a interface itself. And I'm not sure if this question is not to opinion based to be a fit for SO

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Is there another board/forum where I can more opinionated feedback?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChangeProperty is virtual, so if you just want to modify the behaviour of one of the inherited ("child") classes, you can just do it:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject: BaseObject
{    
    protected virtual void ChangeProperty<T>(
        ref T property,
        T value,
        string propertyName)
    {
        // Do my own stuff
        base.ChangeProperty(property, value, propertyName);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to "modify" (or better, I would say *augment*) the ChangeProperty method for every BaseObject, I would go your way.

I would probably use a more "general" approach, like:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public IPropertyChangeHelper propertyChangeHelper { get; set; }

    ...

    public void ChangeProperty<T>(
        ref T property,
        T value,
        string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyChangeHelper != null)
           propertyChangeHelper.beforeChange(value, propetyName)
        ...

        if (propertyChangeHelper != null)
           propertyChangeHelper.afterChange(value, propetyName)
    }
}
```

Modifying the interface accordingly. But is up to personal preferences/trading safety (who is going to use your classes?) for flexibility.

That is, if you do not want to use an AOP framework!

The problem you are facing is quite common: augument methods with cross-cutting concepts ("aspects") like logging, security, ecc...

C#, per se, does not have AOP facilities, but there are .NET libraries that can assist you.
Just as an example, take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), or at Castle [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), or again at this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx).

Comment: @Lozenzo Thanks for the info. As you've correctly guessed, I want to be able to modify ChangeProperty for a single child OR for all BaseObject. I've had a quick look at the DynamicProxy you suggested and it might be useful, though I'll have to play around with it to see how it goes.